# Center align stackView while maintaining fixed spacing

Tags: swift, alignment, uilabel, uistackview

I have a UITableViewCell that is supposed to show two labels out of which one can be either 1 or 2 lines in height. The labels are supposed to have a fixed spacing between each other. Together they are always expected to vertically centered within the cell.

I thought that a UIStackView would be a good solution for this but none of the distribution options allow for a fixed spacing between the items. What's a good solution to the scenario described? I've attached an illustration (gray = cell, line = cell's vertical center) to make this easier[image]

Comment: A little confusing... Are your images showing what you're *currently* getting, but you don't want that? Or are those images of what you *want* to achieve, but can't get?

Comment: The image is what I want but am not able to achieve with a UIStackView so far.

Comment: OK.... your images appear to show a **Constant** row height of `210` ... Is that correct? That is, the cells / row height should not change based on the number of lines?

Comment: That is correct. But I'm not sure if that would influence the result? The goal is to have the two labels (as a sum) centered around the row's centerX axis.

Answer (score 0):

You're images are not actually showing the labels centered vertically.

With one line in each label, they are both 20.5-pts tall (assuming default font/size), with a 12-pt gap. Fine. Easy enough to center on the Y axis.

With **two** lines in the top label, it becomes (20.5-pts + 0-gap + 20.5-pts), and then 12-pt gap, and then 20.5-pt single-line label. So it's not an even distribution of the lines of text, which is why vertical centering of the stack view doesn't place the center-line through the center-line of the second line of text.

If you examine your image (which I'm assuming you laid-out by hand), you have `201` pixels between the top of the view and the top of the top label, but only `198` pixels between the bottom of the bottom label and the bottom of the view.

If that's really how you want it to lay out, you can do this:

- set a fixed row height
- give your stack view a centerYAxis constraint
- keep a reference to that constraint

Then, override `willDisplay cell`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let c = cell as? ExampleCell {

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        let topHeight = c.topLabel.frame.height
        let botHeight = c.bottomLabel.frame.height

        if topHeight > botHeight {
            c.stackViewCenterYConstraint.constant = 6.0
        } else if botHeight > topHeight {
            c.stackViewCenterYConstraint.constant = -6.0
        } else {
            c.stackViewCenterYConstraint.constant = 0.0
        }

    }
}
```

The value of `6.0` is 1/2 of the stack view spacing (12 * 0.5 == 6), so you'll need to change that if you change your spacing.

Here is the result (red line is vertical mid-line):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, in my image the axis is off by 1 pixel, but other than that everything is centered. Was also more meant as an illustration and not to be taken literal. Your approach is interesting, will give it a try. Was overall hoping to find a solution where I don't have to use fixed parameters (other than the 12px spacing between the labels) that I can apply within the cell layout.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the `6.0` value, you could add a function in your cell to return its stackView's `.spacing`, and divide it by two.